# How to interface skype with a browser

Tags: javascript, browser, skype

Does skype have an api from which it would be possible to create a browser plugin so that when a call comes into skype it will let the current web page know that there is a call (with the caller ID information)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are looking for [Skype Accessories (the Skype Public API)](http://developer.skype.com/accessories).

> Skype Accessories enhance the Skype experience for Skype users. They can be hardware products or software applications, but they're all created by developers who use the Skype Public API, a text-based protocol, to interact with Skype software.

Comment: Please show some example @Matt Ball, its great to see answer from you.

Answer (score 2):

There is no server-side solution for this that won't breach Skype's TOS (logging into the Skype network using user credentials).