# Skype for business with node.js web integration

Tags: node.js, skype, skype-for-business

So i saw this post a few years back, the conclusion was there's no solution back then;
[How to interface skype with a browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965499/how-to-interface-skype-with-a-browser)

I recently found that there's a skype-api; i couldn't figure out whether it's for making skype video/audio call through node.js back end or what. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/skype-api
https://www.npmjs.com/package/skype-rest

Can someone help me to understand:
1. What's the updated status to the previous question;
2. What's this skype-api got to do with skype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly recommand you to take a look at twillio.com   it does everthing you could think of a phone system would do